# How to construct panel data data frame in R from individual variables efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to construct panel data in R. I know how to do do it in principle but not how to do it efficiently.

My desired outcome would look like:

```
state     city
delta     A
delta     B
delta     C
gamma     D
gamma     E
...
omega     X
```

I have a variables for individual states that contain cities:

```
delta <- c("A", "B", "C") 
gamma <- c("F", "E)
...
```

I know that I could simply use:

```
state <- c("delta", "delta", "delta", "gamma" ... )
city <- c("A", "B", "C", "D" ...)

df <- data.frame(state, city)
```

but given that I have very large number of sates and cities using the above would be very time consuming.

Is there any more efficient way in which the variables `delta`, `gamma` .... can be somehow combined directly into dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stack` -

```
delta <- c("A", "B", "C") 
gamma <- c("F", "E")

stack(dplyr::lst(delta, gamma))

#  values   ind
#1      A delta
#2      B delta
#3      C delta
#4      F gamma
#5      E gamma
```

Answer (score 2):

Collect all object names into a list `lst` and proceed as follows.  I emptied my current folder and then proceeded.

```r
delta <- c("A", "B", "C")
gamma <- c("F", "E")

lst <- ls()
library(tidyverse)
map_df(lst, ~get(.x) %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames('City') %>%
      mutate(State = .x))
#>   City State
#> 1    A delta
#> 2    B delta
#> 3    C delta
#> 4    F gamma
#> 5    E gamma
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget` with `stack`

```
stack(mget(c('delta', 'gamma')))
```